# wxSuperToolTip changes position on SetMessage

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm creating a wx.agw.SuperToolTip.  I'm updating the message in the tip every few seconds, and if the tip is showing when the message updates the tip is redrawn in a different position.

The new position seems to be relative to the original position's relation to the top left corner of the screen, but that could just be coincidence.

Also, if I modify `wx.lib.agw.supertooltip.ToolTipWindowBase.Invalidate()` by commenting out the call to `self.CalculateBestSize()` the problem goes away.  Of course then the window won't resize, so that's no solution.

I'm using wxPython 2.8.12.1.

Here's an app that demonstrates the problem:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title,
                          pos=(150, 150), size=(350, 225))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Hover over this")

        self._superTip = SuperToolTip("")
        self._superTip.SetHeader("Heyo!")
        self._superTip.SetTarget(btn)
        self._superTip.EnableTip(True)
        self._superTip.SetDrawHeaderLine(True)
        self._superTip.SetDrawFooterLine(True)
        self._superTip.SetStartDelay(1)
        self._superTip.SetEndDelay(60)
        currentFooterFont = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
        currentFooterFont.SetPointSize(6)
        currentFooterFont.SetWeight(wx.NORMAL)
        self._superTip.SetFooterFont(currentFooterFont)
        self._superTip.SetFooter('(Click to close)')
        self._superTip.ApplyStyle("Blue Glass")
        self._superTip.SetDropShadow(True)

        self.ttTimer = wx.Timer(self)

        self.ttText = 'What the?'

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer, self.ttTimer)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.ttTimer.Start(2000)

        panel.Layout()



    def onTimer(self, evt):
        self._superTip.SetMessage(self.ttText)
        self.ttText += '?'

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, "STT error demo")
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)

        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp(redirect=True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Any thoughts on how I can update a visible tooltip without its location changing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: any reason you are still working with 2.8 release?

Comment: Because updating to 3.x breaks a lot of things.

Comment: The problem is not showing up on Linux. It seems to work well.